# how to push sql server update to web UI

Tags: sql-server, real-time

We have an ETL package that writes data to the SQL Server. Data is displayed on ASP.Net web pages. Occasionally ETL may recognize an alarm condition (it is also written to the database). In this case UI must be notified immediately. What is the appropriate technology to push something from either ETL or SQL Server to ASP.Net UI?
StreamInsight appears to be an overkill. Cache Dependency doesn't seem to include a way to push events to the client. What is your recommendation?

Comment: My hunch is that you're going to have to stick with a pull/polling model, unless you write some custom "push" code in an SSIS script (assuming you're using SSIS for ETL) in the "failure" path of the SSIS task, assuming that such a thing is possible. You'd have to include a listener in your client code and the connect to that from the SSIS package or through some message queue. It's doable, but it may be more portable to set up logging in SSIS and periodically check the status of the ETL with a combination of `sp_help_job` and querying the logs for the exact error if needed (for UI purposes).

Comment: My current idea is to create cache that reads from the alarms table, make it auto-update with cache dependency and poll it every few seconds. But I am new to this area and I thought maybe there is a more appropriate way to push from SQL Server.

Comment: Are you looking to push errors, or everything?

Comment: Just errors. Not SQL errors but some specific and relatively rare events that SSIS identifies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of Query Notifications in SQL Server. Query notifications allow applications to be notified when data has changed. This feature is particularly useful for applications that provide a cache of information from a database, such as a Web application, and need to be notified when the source data is changed. 
For more information see this link [msdn link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9x04ed2.aspx)

Hope it helps !!

**EDIT :**
You can use the SqlCacheDependency class in your case. The SqlCacheDependency makes use of the SqlDependency to remove data from the cache when a dependency changes. It derives from the CacheDependency base class, which is one of the parameters used when inserting an item into the cache.
When a SqlCacheDependency is created with a database and table name, it will monitor the table for changes. Monitoring the table is done with the polling features that are available with SQL Server. The way polling works is by attaching a trigger to the table to be monitored that is fired with each insert, update, and delete statement. The trigger increments a number in a status table for this source table to indicate that the table has been changed. When a table is being monitored, this status table is polled for that number to check whether it has changed.
You can get a lot of example of implementing this on google. One such is presented [here](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=263)

Comment: I saw that description but my understanding was that it is only to update cache. Application still has to pull cache on timer frequently enough to make it appear as "push". Am I right or there is a way to plug in a delegate from the application that will be called?